# Jquery - Hide every visible DIV but not #div1 (and all childs)

Tags: jquery, hide

here is my code
$("div:visible:not(#div1)").hide();

The Problem: the DIV-Childs from #div1 are hided too :(

kind reagards
Peter

Comment: there was a 9min. limit  ... so i decide to accept the answer later ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div:visible").not('#div1, #div1 *').hide();
```

or if you only want to exclude children elements of type `div`:

```
$("div:visible").not('#div1, #div1 div').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div:visible:not(#div1)").hide();
$("#div1").children().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a child selector uses the "greater than" character:

```
#div1 > div (all div children of div id "div1")
```

---

The space between two selectors targets all *descendants*:

```
#div1 div (all div descendants of div id "div1")
```